# Separar resultados por semanas

Tags: sql

tengo mi siguientes 2 tablas una donde debo insertar los resultados separados por semana de cada socio, y la tabla que contiene toda la información de cada socio.

mi estructura de mi tabla base es la siguiente:(contiene toda la info)

```
[dbo].[VentaxSNySemana](
[SocioNeg] [varchar](max) NULL,
[Embarques] [int] NULL,
[Ventas] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
[Costos] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
[Profit] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
[ProfitxEmb] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
[Anio] [int] NULL,
[Semana] [int] NULL,
[CSemana] [varchar](10) NULL,
```

aqui muestro algunos resultados al consultar esta tabla,son miles asi que solo pondre 4.

```
 [SocioNeg] [Embarques][Ventas][Costos][Profit][Profixemb][Anio][Semana][CSemana]
    Jaime           1      13      114     181     13        2019   3       S4
    Jaime           2      14      120     214     10        2019   3       S4
    Jaime           6      62      28      30       3        2019   5       S6
    Jaime           5      12      28      30       3        2019   5       S6
```

como puedo pasar estos resultados a otra tabla pero que cada socio muestre sus VALUES (embarques,costos,ventas,profit)
semana por semana, si suponiendo que el socio jaime tiene varios embarques pero de diferentes semanas

Mi otra tabla deberia quedar de la siguiente manera

```
[dbo].[ResultadosporSEMANAdeCadaSOCIO](
    [SocioNeg] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [EMBSemna3] [int] NULL,
    [VentSemna3] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [CostSemna3] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [ProfitSemna3] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [ProfitxEmbSemna3] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [CodigoSemna3] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [EMBSemna4] [int] NULL,
    [VentSemna4] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [CostSemna4] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [ProfitSemna4] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [ProfitxEmbSemna4] [decimal](19, 4) NULL,
    [CodigoSemna4] [varchar](max) NULL
```

y aqui suponiendo que quedara de esta forma ya llena:

```
[SocioNeg][EMBSemna3][VentSemna3][CostSemna3][ProfitSemna3][ProfitxEmbSemna3][CodigoSemna3] [EMBSemna5][VentSemna5][CostSemna5][ProfitSemna5][ProfitxEmbSemna5][CodigoSemna5]
    Jaime   3           27       234            395                3        S4                  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL NULL
```

Los NULL seria si en caso de que el socio en la semana 5 no tenga nada registrado.

Comment: puedes hacerle un inner join tu llave puede ser socioNeg y EMBSemana3

Comment: agrupando mediante la semana con un `GROUP BY`

Comment: me podrian dar un ejemplo ?

Comment: ¿Cuantas semanas vas a manejar como máximo en tu reporte?

Comment: 53 semanas es el máximo de mi reporte

Answer (score 0):

La forma más elemental de resolverlo, es construir una consulta agrupada por `SocioNeg` y con funciones de agregación condicionales a cada semana, construir cada columna:

```
SELECT  SocioNeg,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN Embarques ELSE 0 END)   AS EMBSemna1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN Ventas ELSE 0 END)      AS VentSemna1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN Costos ELSE 0 END)      AS CostSemna1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN Profit ELSE 0 END)      AS ProfitSemna1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN Profixemb ELSE 0 END)   AS ProfitxEmbSemna1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Semana = 1 THEN CSemana ELSE NULL END)  AS CodigoSemna1,

    ..

    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN Embarques ELSE 0 END)  AS EMBSemna53,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN Ventas ELSE 0 END)     AS VentSemna53,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN Costos ELSE 0 END)     AS CostSemna53,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN Profit ELSE 0 END)     AS ProfitSemna53,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN Profixemb ELSE 0 END)  AS ProfitxEmbSemna53,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Semana = 53 THEN CSemana ELSE NULL END) AS CodigoSemna53

    FROM VentaxSNySemana
    GROUP BY SocioNeg
```

Sino, dependiendo de la versión de `sql-server` puedes investigar el uso de la clausula [`PIVOT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15), de cualquier forma, te habrás dado cuenta que hay que escribir bastante código, es que tienen algo así como 318 columnas a configurar (6 por 53 semanas), podrías escribir una sentencia dinámica que construya esta consulta, pero pierdes cualquier posibilidad de optimización que pueda aplicar el motor.